# How to execute base R function on Shiny reactive table subset?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm trying to create a Shiny/flexdashboard Markdown file, and I've stuck the following in a R code chunk. Basically, it subsets the input dataframe using two inputs - the second input depends on the first:

```
output$Box1 = renderUI(selectInput('sector', 
                                 'Sector', 
                                 c(levels(test$Sector),"pick one"),
                                 "pick one") )

output$Box2 = renderUI(
if (is.null(input$sector) || input$sector == "pick one"){return() 
}else selectInput('FA', 
                  'Functional Area', 
                  c(levels(test$FA[which(test$Sector == input$sector)]),"pick one"),
                  "pick one"))

subdata1 = reactive(test[which(test$Sector == input$sector),])
subdata2 = reactive(subdata1()[which(subdata1()$FA == input$FA),])
renderDataTable({subdata2()},  options = list(dom = 'lpt'))
```

Now, this works fine to subset the data frame (Sector, then FA), and the subsetted data frame is visible in the dashboard via `renderDataTable`.

What I'd like to do is to perform things like `table` on the reactive data subset, to create a contingency table on factor levels:

```
 data1 <- reactive(table(subdata2()$UserCountry))
```

and then further use this new table, for example:

```
renderDataTable({data1()},  options = list(dom = 'lpt'))
```

When I try this, the new table doesn't render.

Is there a way of running this successfully?

Comment: Need a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
data1 <- reactive(as.data.frame(table(subdata2()$UserCountry)))
```

While values returned by `table()` are printed like matrices on the console, they have their own distinct class (`table`). It is not handled by `renderDataTable()`, which requires a `data.frame` or `matrix`.